# SwiftUI alignment of "rating" views in two separate rows in Form for macOS and iOS

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, alignment

Writing a Multiplatform app initially for macOS and iOS that uses a master detail view structure and within the detail view is a `Form` and many `Section`s, one of which contains two structs that represent a user's rating (of food) for enjoyment and consumption.

Here is the code for the enjoyment rating...

```
struct Rating: View {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colourScheme
    @Binding var rating: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Enjoyment")
                .padding(.trailing, 12.0)
#if os(iOS)
            Spacer()
#endif
            ForEach(0..<5) { counter in
                Image(systemName: rating > counter ? "star.fill" : "star")
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        if rating == 1 {
                            rating = 0
                        }
                        else {
                            rating = counter + 1
                        }
                    }
                    // this line for image system name = "circle.fill" : "circle"
                    //.padding(.trailing, counter != 4 ? 2.5 : 0) 
            }
            .shadow(color: colourScheme == .light ? .gray : .white, radius: colourScheme == .light ? 1.0 : 2.0, x: 0, y: 0)
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
    }
}
```

The consumption rating is very similar with minor changes.

So far these look good on iOS because the (iOS only) Spacer() pushes each `Rating` view to the right or trailing edge of the row and my .padding modifier hack for the circle image makes the spacing between each image "about right".

While I'm struggling to figure out how to align the "dots" for the macOS target, I'm also struggling to figure out how to align each image programmatically, so that if I changed the image the alignment would work.

See screenshots below (that illustrate how the five `Image`s do not align).

**iOS**

[image: iOS screenshot]

**macOS**

[image: macOS screenshot]

I've read a few blogs on the `.alignmentGuide` modifier including [Alignment guides in SwiftUI](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/03/11/alignment-guides-in-swiftui/) by Majid Jabrayilov.

It seems to be the way I should go but I'm stuck in my attempts on how to work this out.

Comment: Why do you implement the `Spacer` as iOS-only? It's supported on macOS too.

Comment: You are using macros there that is the issue! You should let View use Spacer in macOS

Comment: @ScottMatthewman it’s a UI decision… for iOS the right alignment “seems” appropriate and for macOS, especially on a larger screen, the rating elements look better alongside the labels (and better match Apple’s Human Interface Guidelines for macOS).

Comment: @swiftPunk I don’t understand why using a macro is an issue?

Comment: Because you need that Spacer for you, when you use that macro, you limit your view to use it! @andrewbuilder

Answer (score 1):

I've added a comment about the use of `Spacer()` between your label and your rating control, but separately it's worth looking at the rating control itself.

Firstly, right now you're relying on the five elements sharing an HStack with the label, and using conditional padding logic within the loop to control the spacing between elements.

That part would be easier if you give your rating element its own HStack. That way, spacing between elements can be determined using the stack's `spacing` attribute without having to worry about whether or not you're on the last loop iteration. For example:

```swift
HStack(spacing: 2.5) {
  ForEach(0..<5) {
    Image(systemName: "circle")
    // etc.
  }
}
```

In terms of aligning the child elements of a rating view so that they align with a similar view below regardless of the symbol being used, you can constrain the frame width of each child element to be the same, regardless of what image they're displaying.

You can accomplish that by adding a `.frame()` modifier to each child element in the loop:

```swift
HStack {
  ForEach(0..<5) {
    Image(systemName: "xxx")
      .frame(width: 40, alignment: .center)
  }
}
```

You'd obviously need to pick a width that works for you - and you could mix this with a `spacing` attribute on the HStack as well.

Comment: Scott great answer thanks for taking time to clearly explain your solution. In my first draft of my Q I noted that I didn't want to use a `.frame` modifier but then decided to delete it so it left that as a possible solution... but I suspect the issue remains... this type of solution is not flexible enough. If we have longer text (for translations) or a bigger font (with dynamic type) the `VStack(spacing:)` and `.frame(width:)` modifier may not be enough. I'm hoping for a generic solution that is completely dynamic (and reusable).

Comment: I get you. It may be worth looking into defining any numeric values using the @ScaledMetric property wrapper, such that the values will scale alongside any dynamic type changes.